How to Insert one Id with same duplicate Id in next column
I have a customer tables in sql
I have cid identity column I want generated duplicate value in SID COLUMN
| CID      |  NAME    |SID
| -------- | -------- |
|    1       Aman.     1                   
     2     | Cash     |2

I want to CID value same add  Automatically same Cid values in SID column
``
Then output like
CID|   NAME | SID
3  |  DINESH| 3     
4. | Raman. | 4

Insert into customer(cid, name)
values(3, 'Dinesh') 
select sid from customer where cid=3


I have formatted your post, can you please clarify this sentence: "I want to CID value same add in SID column next when add record"

values(3, 'Dinesh', 3) ?

Is CID an identity column for which you wish to duplicate the generated value in the SID column? You might be able to do this by inserting null or a placeholder value and then using an AFTER INSERT trigger to copy the value. The SQL server SEQUENCE object might also be an option if incorporated into an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger.

Please write query sir

This feels like an XY Problem. If you want to INSERT the same value, why doesn't the suggestion from @DaleK work? If you don't want to use a literal, why not define a variable, and INSERT the same variable into the different columns?

Maybe you just want a computed column? ALTER TABLE customer ADD sid AS (cid);

You can use a trigger to automatically copy the information about CID to SID after your insert. So, in your case, it will be:
CREATE TRIGGER trg_insertingCustomer
ON YOUR_CUSTOMER_TABLE 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE YOUR_CUSTOMER_TABLE
    SET YOUR_CUSTOMER_TABLE.SID = INSERTED.CID
    FROM YOUR_CUSTOMER_TABLE 
    INNER JOIN inserted AS INSERTED ON YOUR_CUSTOMER_TABLE.CID = INSERTED.CID;
END;

The inserted here represents the newly inserted rows. It ensures that only those ones would have their SID set with their CID. It is automatically created by SQL Server
CREATE TRIGGER documentation

I would also check to see if the SID is NULL before performing the update via the trigger. This would be to account for someone inserting the value directly and expecting it to be the value inserted.

Sir please write query I don't understand how it is possible please

@NehaPandey - I suggest that you take some time to read up on triggers so that you understand what they are, how they work, the significance of the inserted and deleted special tables. There are many tutorials out there. It is not wise to cut and paste trigger code written by someone else without first understanding what the code is doing, so that you have the ability to debug and modify their behaviors as needed.
